# RuntimeWarning and Change in Plot Axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
min_width = (min(widths_in_frame) * 0.00633217993)
log_val = np.log(min_width/1.8)
widths.append(log_val)
frames.append(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
```

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

I am getting this warning here and my frames axis is shrunk (from 1600 to 1400)

Comment: `np.log(0)` → `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log`. Hard to say more without a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `min_width` after calculation `(min(widths_in_frame) * 0.00633217993)` somehow becomes equal to 0 or very close to 0, so it is not possible to calculate `min_width/1.8`

In order to find out which stage the problem is from, you can use some prints before and after `min_width`, for example like this:

```
print(f"widths_in_frame = {widths_in_frame}")
print(f"min(widths_in_frame) = {min(widths_in_frame)}")

min_width = (min(widths_in_frame) * 0.00633217993)

print(f"min_width = {min_width}")
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix that? Have It calculated values for very low values?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no way to fix this problem, because mathematically, the operation of dividing 0 by any number is not possible!
The only way is that you manage the program inputs so that **min_width** is not equal to zero.
Unfortunately, I do not have complete information about your program, I cannot give more guidance.

Comment: min_width is never Zero. It can be close to 0. I would like to let the log function calculate log for smaller numbers (which mathematically, exist for every number x; Lim: x -> 0)